# Making LFTP mirror to one flat directory

Tags: ftp, lftp

Is there any way to make LFTP mirror remote files at ftp server to one "flat" local directory?

Answer (score 1):

In the meantime (lftp v4.8.0 and v4.8.4), a --flat option has been added to the mirror command in lftp, but it has not been documented in the man page.
https://github.com/lavv17/lftp/search?q=%22--flat%22&unscoped_q=%22--flat%22